# Android: How to set activity that shows only once (when app is installed)

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to make application with activity "UserIntro" that shows ONLY when app is installed and asks user some questions about himself. But latter when user starts app again that activity doesn't appear.

Does anyone know how to accomplish that?
Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Use shared preferences to store a flag whether the user has/hasn't entered this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Shared preferences to store a boolean first time the app launches. As the boolean won't exist first time, just check for it's existance upon startup and manually launch an activity.